# how to find other (checkbox)view in a custom listview

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, listener

I am new so I may not explain the situation well. Please let me know if you need more info.

I am trying to implement a listview like this:

```
 [textview][button][checkbox] 
 [textview][button][checkbox]
 [textview][button][checkbox] 
 [textview][button][checkbox]
```

I　want other checkbox unchecked automatically when I click one of them. So it is like a single choice. I write following codes which can implement multiple choice but when I try to switch it to single choice I got trouble.

in checkBoxOnClickListener I cannot find other (checkbox)view and toggle them. Any suggestion pals? Let me know if you think my express skills poor.

Thank you.

```
    public class MyAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {

    Map<Integer, Boolean> map;

    LayoutInflater mInflater;

    private List<? extends Map<String, ?>> mList;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<Map<String, String>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);
        map = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        mList = data;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            map.put(i, false);
        }
        if (data.get(0).get("value").equals("Male") || data.get(0).get("value").equals("Yes")) {
            map.put(1, true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.rapid_diagnosis_row, null);
        }
        TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.multiple_question);
        textView.setText((String) mList.get(position).get("value"));

        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.multiple_checkbox);
        checkBox.setChecked(map.get(position));

        // save position and checking status into tag
        checkBox.setTag(position);
        checkBox.setOnClickListener(checkBoxOnClickListener);

        return convertView;
    }

    public OnClickListener checkBoxOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // ((CheckBox) v).toggle();
            boolean checked = ((CheckBox) v).isChecked();
            if (checked) {
                ((CheckBox) v).setChecked(true);
            } else {
                ((CheckBox) v).setChecked(false);
            }
            int p = (Integer) (v.getTag());
            mSimpleAdapter.map.put(p, checked);

                            // this cannot works, helppp
            ListView lv = ((ListView) (v.getParent().getParent()));
            (CheckBox) cb = lv.findViewWithTag(1);
            cb.toggle();
                   .....................
```

...............
            }
        };
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the problem that `findViewWithTag(1)` is returning null? It might be that `findViewWithTag()` does not recursively search for your tag. If you go up parent twice that puts you at your `ListView` and `findViewWithTag()` will then be looking at the layout objects to be tagged.

You should go through each of the `ListView`'s children and then find the check box each one holds. It's hard to tell from the code snippet here, but why are you using run time set Tags to try to find your check boxes rather than IDs?

Comment: Thank you Thomas. The problem solved. Actually I only need to make it single choice only if there are two rows. The codes ugly but work: ListView lv = (ListView) (v.getParent().getParent());
     View view = lv.findViewWithTag(Math.abs(p - 1));
     CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) (view.findViewById(R.id.multiple_checkbox));
     cb.toggle();

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example with "EditText"

v is the calling view

pv is its parent

event_id_tag is the tag I gave it on the main activity.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
  View pv = (View)v.getParent();
  EditText et = (EditText)pv.findViewWithTag("event_id_tag");
```